# NSURLSessionConfiguration and timeoutIntervalForResource for NSURLSessionDelegate didCompleteWithError

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Wondering if someone can provide their two cents. Below code successfully triggers `didCompleteWithError` `NSURLSessionDelegate` method upon `timeoutIntervalForResource` timeout.

```objectivec
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.xxx.xxx"];
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20.0f;
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20.0f;
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

But setting the timeout like below does not

```objectivec
self.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20.0f;
self.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20.0f;
```

The goal I am trying to achieve is to change the `timeoutIntervalForResource` depending on different API

```objectivec
if(needs less timeout){
   self.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 8.0f;
} else{
   self.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30.0f;
}
```

Comment: BTW, if your resource timeouts are so short, it begs the question of why you’re using background session at all. We usually only go for all the background session overhead when we've got requests that can _not_ be completed within 30 seconds (i.e., the amount of time that you can [extend your app’s background execution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time?language=objc)).

Comment: @Rob Thanks for getting back. Trying to get back on all your comments. Yes I tried the timeoutInterval for NSMutableURLRequest and that does not trigger didCompleteWithError. From few online searches seems like setting timeoutIntervalForResource is the way to go from iOS 8 and later.

Comment: @Rob I was not sure if having multiple session was a good approach but its good to know that is an option as well.  Also, those timeouts were just an arbitrary numbers :). But any clue as to why setting timeoutIntervalForRequest for config triggers didCompleteWithError but self.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20.0f does not?

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Below code successfully triggers `didCompleteWithError` `NSURLSessionDelegate` method upon `timeoutIntervalForResource` timeout.
>
> ```objectivec
> NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.xxx.xxx"];
> config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20.0f;
> config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20.0f;
> self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
> ```
>
> But setting the timeout like below does not
>
> ```objectivec
> self.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20.0f;
> self.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20.0f;
> ```

You are attempting to change the configuration settings *after* the session was instantiated. You must adjust the configuration settings before the session is instantiated. As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1411477-configuration?language=objc) say (emphasis added):

> Beginning in iOS 9 and OS X 10.11, `NSURLSession` objects store a *copy* of the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object passed to their initializers, such that a session’s configuration is immutable after initialization. Any further changes to mutable properties on the configuration object passed to a session’s initializer or the value returned from a session’s configuration property do not affect the behavior of that session. However, you can create a new session with the modified configuration object.

Comment: this makes sense why it does not trigger the delegate methods when setting the values the second way. But this actually limits the way we would be able to set the timeoutIntervalForResource for the session's configuration depending on different task since we can only set background configuration once for our session with that specific identifier

Comment: “But this actually limits the way we would be able to set ...” - Perhaps it does, but it is obviously a conscious design choice on their part. You could always submit a feature request with the “[Feedback Assistant](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)”, but don’t be surprised if you get a generic ”functions as designed” reply. Regardless, good luck and happy coding.